# Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, positioning

In the PGF/TikZ manual, sometimes I see the option `right of=somenode` instead of `right=of somenode`. They look very similar, but the effects are different.  The distance between nodes positioned with the latter option is boundary-to-boundary, as stated in the manual. However, with the first option, it seems that the distance is shorter. I couldn't find any explanation of the first option in the manual.

My question is: what is the difference between the two options? Is there any explanation in the manual that I missed?

Comment: A bookkeeping comment: in the v2.10 manual the deprecated `above right of=` appears on page 192 in the last example of `/tikz/swap`.

Answer (score 141, accepted):

The `right of` key isn't described in the manual at all (at least I couldn't find it). In fact, those keys are deprecated. The file `pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex` contains the following code:

```
% The following are deprecated:
\tikzoption{above of}{\tikz@of{#1}{90}}%
\tikzoption{below of}{\tikz@of{#1}{-90}}%
\tikzoption{left of}{\tikz@of{#1}{180}}%
\tikzoption{right of}{\tikz@of{#1}{0}}%
\tikzoption{above left of}{\tikz@of{#1}{135}}%
\tikzoption{below left of}{\tikz@of{#1}{-135}}%
\tikzoption{above right of}{\tikz@of{#1}{45}}%
\tikzoption{below right of}{\tikz@of{#1}{-45}}%
\def\tikz@of#1#2{%
  \def\tikz@anchor{center}%
  \let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\relax%
  \tikz@addtransform{%
    \expandafter\tikz@extract@node@dist\tikz@node@distance and\pgf@stop%
    \pgftransformshift{\pgfpointpolar{#2}{\tikz@extracted@node@distance}}}%
  \def\tikz@node@at{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}}
\def\tikz@extract@node@dist#1and#2\pgf@stop{%
  \def\tikz@extracted@node@distance{#1}}
```

That is, the center of the new node is placed `node distance` away from the center anchor of the old node (where only the first number in `node distance` is used). You can see why this option is deprecated if you try a wide node:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong};
  \node[right of=a,font=\bfseries,blue] (b) {node b};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: example of incorrect positioning]

On the other hand `right=of` would measure the `node distance` (defaulting to 1cm) from the east anchor of node **a** to the west anchor of node **b**:

[image: example of correct positioning]

Note that in order to use the `right=of ⟨node⟩` syntax, you need to include the TikZ library `positioning` via `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`.

Comment: By default, `positioning` measures the distance between the borders of the nodes. But, with the `on grid` option, it measures the distance between the centers of the nodes.

Comment: WARNING: Using the `positioning` library will render your images unscalable (if no explicitly nodes are present). This is a huge drawback if `tikz` is used with `tikzscale` and should therefore be mentioned...

Comment: @Dux I've not had that problem, though I don't use `tikzscale` extensively.